# How to remove nova rambler virus

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, antivirus

I downloaded some freeware recently on my mac and now all my chrome urls have nova.rambler.ru prepended.

I've never had a virus or trojan on here so I have clue where to even start.

I've done search after search but everything is for PC or tries to sell you some sort of anti-virus software.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: there's a selection of solutions (including Chrome) found at http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-nova-rambler-ru-virus.html

Answer (score 0):

Your Chrome shortcut may have been affected. The second solution in this [article](http://www.okpckit.com/how-to-remove-nova-rambler-ru-from-iechromefirefox/) mentioned how to fix it. Of course, ignore the downloads on this page.

Go to Google Chrome shortcut by right-clicking on its icon and selecting Properties.
Delete the additional argument at the end of the Target section.

This may do the trick.

Also, remember to check your Hosts file and make sure nothing suspicious is added there.
If the malware can't be removed, try some free anti-malware programs like Malwarebytes and AdwCleaner.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

- first of all, install another Browser (Firefox)
- export your Favourites if you are afraid to loose them ("Bookmarks", "Bookmarks Manager", "Organize" and choose "Export to HTML files")
- exit from Chrome
- go to the "Applications" folder and drag the Chrome icon into the Trashbox.
- Then click on the "Go" button on the upper Finder tool bar, choose "Go to Folder" and write this command:
  ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome
- select all the Chrome folders and all the Chrome files displayed (you are inside the Chrome folder that is still inside your OS) and drag all of them inside the Trashbox
  Now Chrome is completely uninstalled from your OS. Now:
- open Firefox, download the Chrome.dmg file from the Chrome official site and open it
- drag the Install file inside the "Application" folder
- launch Chrome
  Now you have a "virgin" and "clear" Chrome installation. Then You have to:
- sign in with your Google account
- import your Bookmarks (but I think they will be already there after I have logged in)
- uninstall Firefox if You want or use both of them if You want.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the hosts file is affected. The shortcut should also be checked. I recommend you to scan your Mac with the latest version of Bitdefender antivirus (you will find a nice review, [here](https://antivirusprotection.reviews/review/bitdefender/)). What is interesting is that Bitdefender also checks the hosts file (probably affceted) for any unusual change.

You can use it in "Trial" mode for 30 days, so you don't need to pay anything.